# Does a Lightsail launch script only run at new instance initialisation?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, amazon-lightsail

When creating a new Ubuntu Lightsail instance and adding a launch script is the script you enter only run when you FIRST initialize the instance and NOT every time you reboot or restart the same instance? I would love to automate updates and install applications when I create the instance, but I would also like to run updates and start servers when the instance is rebooted or restarted.

Can I (should I) use the launch script for this? Or would it be better to create a second script to do all the tasks after reboot?